# How to add more than one list box in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my windows phone 7 app i have to add more than one list box. My requirement is user can scroll the page to see all the items. But i don't know how to add multiple list box in one page. I have try like this.

```
  <Grid x:Name="testUIContainer" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,0,2,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
              MaxWidth="477">
            <ScrollViewer.Content>
                <StackPanel Margin="0, 30, 0, 0 ">
                    <Rectangle  Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="Header" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Width="480" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FF01A1DB" />

                    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="listBox1" Width="476" BorderBrush="#00410D0D">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                        <Border BorderBrush="Wheat" BorderThickness="1">
                                            <Image  Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="firstName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Name="lastName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Name="age" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="listBoxes1" Width="476" BorderBrush="#00410D0D">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                        <Border BorderBrush="Wheat" BorderThickness="1">
                                            <Image  Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="firstName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Name="lastName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Name="age" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer.Content>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But here i can not see the second list box. This is example only. I have to add 4 to 5 list box in a page. Please let me know how to add multiple list box in one page. Or there is any other option to show the list of items.

My Requirment:-
[image]

Comment: You cannot scroll to the second `ListBox` or it's not there? Also setting `Grid.Row="0"` against `ListBox` has not effect. `ScrollViewer` is direct child of `Grid` and `ListBox` is child of `StackPanel` which is child of that `ScrollViewer`. In your case whole `ScrollViewer` will be in the first row

Comment: ListBox *is* a way to show a list of items and you generally need **one** ListBox per list.

Comment: @user2845346, and because you set `Height="Auto"` your `ScrollViewer` is given as much space as it needs to grow to accommodate all children hence you won't see scroll bar.

Comment: Hi Toni Petrina. Thanks for reply. I accept that list box is only using for show a list of items. But i have 3 different types of list. What i am trying to do mean, In google play store when we select one application it will move to one page. In that page we can see the reviews, Screen shots, Similar apps etc. Like that only i am trying to do. Sorry for poor English.

Comment: Hi dkozl. Thanks for reply.. Yes, Now only i noticed that. I will change the code. What i am trying to do mean, In google play store when we select one application it will move to one page. In that page we can see the reviews, Screen shots, Similar apps etc. Like that only i am trying to do. Sorry for poor English. Can you provide any simple samples for this? Please.

Comment: @user2845346 Do those three lists have to be one above another?

Comment: @Toni Petrina.. Yes.. Three lists are one above another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each listbox set the property :

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw 2 options :

You can merge/concat both list in backend, then display it in your view.

```
var result = list1.Concat(list2);
```

You can use another UI. For example, a `PivotItem` could be fit in you case. User could switch from a ListBox to another with horizontal thumb's move.

Comment: Hi @aloisdg. Thanks for your reply. And thanks for hint. PivotItem. This is new to me. I will study and than i will implement. Can you provide me any sample for **PivotItem**? Please.

Comment: Check on google `pivotitem sample` or check [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephanc/archive/2010/05/09/windows-phone-7-pivot-control-sample.aspx) or just open a new template PivotPage in VS.

Comment: Hi @aloisdg. In PivotItem,Panorama are not support Vertical scrolling. :-(

Comment: Why you want a panorama in a pivotitem ?

Comment: Hi @aloisdg.. In my application i am trying to implement one page like Android Play Store Page. In Android play store, when user click one application the page will navigate to another page. In that page we can see the reviews, Screen shots, Similar apps etc. User will scroll in vertically and see all the data. Like that only i am trying to do. But I can not achieve that. I have tried Panorama, Pivot Pages. In this pages i can only scroll in horizontally.

Comment: Hi @aloisdg.. I have attace a sample image. That is my requirement. Please review that and let me know any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have find the answer..!!

```
 <Grid Background="Transparent"  x:Name="testUIContainer" Margin="2,0,2,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ScrollViewer.Content>
            <StackPanel>
                <!--Name of the Person-->
                <Border BorderBrush="Chocolate" Padding="5" BorderThickness="2">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Height="100" Width="100" Margin="-360,0,0,0" Source="/NewExample;component/Images/icon_man.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Name of the Person" Margin="50,-120,0,0" Width="300" Height="50" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="26" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <!--Horizaondal list Box-->
                <ListBox Height="120" Margin="0,0,0,6" Name="imageListBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Width="476" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Wheat" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
                                        <Image  Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel >
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ListBox>

                <!--List Box one.-->
                <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="listBox1" Width="476" BorderBrush="#00410D0D" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Wheat" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Image  Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="firstName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Name="lastName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Name="age" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>


                <!--List Box two.-->
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="listBoxes1" Width="476" BorderBrush="#00410D0D" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Image  Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="firstName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Name="lastName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Name="age" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <!--Similar Apps/Images.-->
                <Image Source="/NewExample;component/Images/Hydrangeas.jpg" Margin="0,0,0,0" />


            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer.Content>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I have disable the list box `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`
Here only one row definition.
ScrollViewer will be in Grid.Row="0"

Now i can scroll all the list boxes, and can add many items in the scroll Viewer.

Thank you to all for giving a valuable tips..!!